# Restful Web Services Issue

Tags: rest, netbeans-8

Can anyone tell me how I can solve the issue which I get in NetBeans when I create Restful Web services using Entity Classes using Netbeans IDE?

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
```

Kind Regards,
Indunil Sanjeewa

Comment: I have no experience with NetBeans or Java in general, but it looks to me that it's just a warning. Are you having any problems with this?

Comment: Seems that the specified `EclipseLink` or `org.eclipse.persistence.*` dependency only supports Java 6 while you are using Java 7. Try to [update the dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence) in your pom.xml